# MongoDB- Error1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

When I try to connect mongdb service i am getting error: 
**

> Windows could not start the MongoDB service on Local Computer

**

***Error1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion***

[image]

Mongodb installed path: C:\MongoDB  //mongod.cfg file inside the MongodB folder not in bin folder

**mongod.cfg file:**

---

```
systemLog:

    destination: file

    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log

storage:

    dbPath: c:\data\db***
```

how do I resolve this error and run a mongodb service

Comment: Probably by looking at the actual error messages in that "sytemLog" you are telling us you know where it is. A lot more useful than "screenshots" with no information at all. Look at the log, and then post the "text" if you don't understand the error listed there.

Comment: log folder is empty

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem with MongoDB 4. In auto generated config file, there is an extra configuration, that caused the problem.

#snmp:
mp:

When i deleted  "mp:", i can finally start the server.

Comment: for me, the line after `#snmp:` was `op:` and commenting that out made it work.

Comment: I recommend **commenting** and not *deleting* it. Use `#` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: in addition to duplicate #snmp entries, mine somehow had an empty line with just a colon   ":" deleted that line and the windows service went green

Answer (score 4):

For me , this error was about `mongod.cfg` file , which I add `security;` authorization `enabled`.
But it should be colon after `security` not semicolon.

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was caused by the server running out of space in the hard disk drive.

Clearing some space solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me the same error occurred when I edited the "mongod.cfg" file and added

```
#security:
  authorization: enabled
```

to `#security`

but the correct syntax is the following:

```
#security:
# authorization: enabled
```

I leave it here in case someone faces the same related issue.

Comment: The # sign is used to comment out lines, so you have disabled authorization on your MongoDb server, which may not be what you intended. To enable authorization you need these lines:
    
    security:  
      authorization: enabled

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this failed:

```
security:
  authorization: 
    enabled
```

And this worked fine:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if **mongod.cfg** is corrupted,
If you changed this confiuration file recently, try to undo the latest changes to see if this is the cause for the failure

```
I wonder why a simple error message cannot be printed in such a common failure
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing space **[ ]** . Re-added it and the service started fine.

net:

port: 00000

bindIp:**[ ]** 000:00:000:0

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the error 1053 when I try to start mongo db server in services option, [services option mongodb server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N16HP.png)
just search services and go to this by scrolling down and you will find this option , just right click and click on start. in case its not working then clear browsing history cache images and files, and then click on start option of mongo db server in services, and it worked so you can also try it.
You are facing the error 1053, fixing of this error is very easy, just clear your cache images and files in browsing history option of Google Chrome and you will be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error happened because of this ## Enterprise-Only Options:
I removed one hashtag then it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35717764)